# How to get current path?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get current path of system.  I use this statement for this purpose  :

```
String currentPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

When I run this statement For Example from `E:\`.  I get `E:\`

but when I run from desktop I get `C:\users\zavarghadim\desktop`.  The last slash `(\)` missed.  Why this happen?  In both type I need last slash `c:\users\zavargadim\desktop\`

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `E:\ ` is the root directory of `E:` drive, `c:\users\zavargadim\desktop` is the  `desktop` directory, they essentially mean the same thing.  You could use `File(String, String)` to construct a directory/path combination if that's what you needed

Comment: You mean you want like this "c:\users\zavargadim\desktop\" ?

Comment: `user.dir` can have or lack a trailing slash depending on any number of factors (how the user entered the directory, operating system, shell options, whatever). Do not rely on it to have a trailing slash or not, and if you need to use that, instead validate it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you user working directory.

```
String currentPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

You need to use getRoot, for getting only root component of this path.

```
Paths.get(currentPath).getRoot()
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new with java I use your idea but the compiler said  :can not find symbol :Paths  .Should I import anything else java.io.*; ?

Comment: Yes.
`import java.nio.file.*;`

Comment: Excuse me when I use your statement gives me this erro  : incompatible type getRoot() required String but found Path

Comment: I use like so  : String currentPath = Paths.get(currentPath).getRoot();

Comment: If you want to cast to string, you need write that:
`String currentPath = Paths.get(currentPath).getRoot().toString();`

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()
```

Comment: Sorry should I use your idea like so  ?                                                     String path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()

Comment: Excuse me your statement gives also c:\users\zavarghadim\desktop NOT c:\users\zavarghadim\desktop\

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The currentpath is the root folder of your current java project. It can be retrieved by using System Property Function

```
String currentpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("current path is:" + currentpath);
```

Comment: I used it but it is not the answer

Comment: May i know what output you really want

Comment: I Have an application and run it in both drivers and desktop  .When I run from d:\ I get d:\ result but when running from dekstop i get this result :  c:\users\zavargadim\desktop  . I want c:\users\zavargadim\desktop\

Comment: You can externally add a \ to your String and that can be used anywhere.                    'String currentpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");'    'String newCurrentPath = currentpath+"\";'